# How would you make HTML text appear disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div containing a span (the span could be a paragraph, too; I don't care):

```
<div id="aDiv">
  <span id="aQuestion">What's next?</span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to toggle the span's text's appearance between disabled and enabled. I've tried stuff along the lines of

```
document.getElementById('aQuestion').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

but haven't had any luck: The text doesn't have that grayed-out "disabled" look. When I inspect the element, I can see the attribute has been added. In fact, even if my original code looks like this:

```
<div id="aDiv">
  <span id="aQuestion" disabled>What's next?</span>
</div>
```

the text doesn't appear disabled.

It seems I'm going down the wrong path, but online searches haven't resulted in a solution. Is there any way to accomplish this? I realize the concept of text being disabled doesn't exactly make sense, since they don't involve user interaction, but I need that look.

The only thing I've come up with is to use CSS, something along these lines:
CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .disableMe {
     color:darkgrey;
   }
</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<span id="aQuestion" class="disableMe">What's next?</span>
```

The JS:

```
document.getElementById('aSpan').classList.remove('disableMe');
```

This kind of gets me around the problem with the text, but some of my text spans will have adjacent spans containing bootstrap icons, and I need these to appear disabled, as well. Am I overlooking something very obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't disable text, only form controls. If you just want it to appear 'greyed out' then adding/removing a class is exactly what you need to do. Is there an issue with your second example?

Comment: You should care about what element types you use. Incorrect usage can be very harmful towards accessibility.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/50/

Comment: @uom-pgregorio: Yep. Thanks. Since you went through the trouble of coming up with a suggestion, I'll mark yours as the answer if you respond in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a span element so it doesn't have a disabled modifier, just create a css class that gives the look you want and use that.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured and will probably have to go with.

Answer (score 0):

span includes only the global attributes. So you cannot disable it. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)